# systemd service dropin, ExecStartPre as root user

Tags: linux, systemd

I have a web service running using systemd, this service runs by its own user, and I would like to execute some ExecStartPre commands but running as root user. So more in detail:

*i.e /lib/systemd/system/webservice.service*

```
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/web
Group=webuser
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/usr/share/web
RuntimeDirectory=web
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0750
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/web --config=/etc/web/config.ini                               

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and I would like to have a drop-in service where it fetches from a web-source the config.ini file

*i.e  /etc/systemd/system/web.service.d/local.conf*

```
[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly=true
RestartSec=5
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
ExecStartPre=+/usr/bin/curl http://some.url --output /etc/web/config.ini 
ExecStartPre=+chown web:web /etc/web/config.ini
```

What is the cleanest way to achieve something like that?